# Linear approximation of the given equation with python3

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I was given a set of raw datum and have to model it by means of some machine learning techniques. After some research, I decided to do with the method of linear approximation.

---

#### Description of the equation.

[image]

- z - depth (meters)
- T(z) - temperature at the depth z
- T(zᵢ) - temperature at the depth zᵢ
- T₀ - temperature at the surface (It is constant and known)
- K - coefficient of geothermal gradient (How the temperature changes with respect to the depth)
- Mᵢ - flow rate of the liquid at the depth zᵢ

  ---

As it is shown from the equation we can find the temperature of the liquid in the any depth of the well bore.

I have list of **depths**, **temperature** and the **flow rate** of the liquid. I have to model an equation according to these datum by means of python3. Currently I use matplotlib library for such type of calculations.

---

Comment: Do you want to do this using Fortran, or assembly language, or something else?

Comment: As I wrote in the title, it should be python3

Comment: Indeed so, my apologies. Please see my answer for an example of non-linear multiple regression with Python 3.

Comment: Can you give an example for your data and what do you want to optimize? I assume you want to get K and c? And you have data for z, T(z) and M_i ? And is it correct to assume the upper case Z and Z_i are actual meant in lower case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of non-linear multiple regression in Python 3, this should easily be adapted to your multiple regression problem.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    t = data[0]
    p_p = data[1]
    return a * (t**alpha) * (p_p**beta)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    # this example uses curve_fit()'s default initial paramter values
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)
```

Comment: It seems like a correct answer. But now, how can I use the list of temperatures in both T(z) and T(zᵢ)? (z and zᵢ are different depths and the temperatures for both of them are given in the list)

Comment: Adapt the x,y,z data and equation to your data and equation. The example illustrates non-linear multiple regression with Python 3. By default, the initial parameter estimates for the solver are all 1.0 however you cam pass in your own parameter estimates if you have them.